# Hyphenated Friendly URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using ASP.Net MVC Core 2.0 and having a hard time getting routing working for hyphenated friendly URLs. I would like the following URL style:

```
admin is the area:
    /admin/invoice-categories/new    - Creates a new invoice category
    /admin/invoice-categories/edit/1 - Edits a invoice category
    /admin/invoice-categories        - Shows the invoice categories list
```

This is my controller code:

```
[Area("admin")]
[Route("[area]/invoice-categories/"]
class InvoiceCategoriesController {
   public IActionResult New() {}
   public IActionResult Edit(int id) {}
   public IActionResult Index() {}
}
```

However, this results in an exception stating the "New, Edit, Index" methods in the controller are ambiguous.

Is there a way to get it to work WITHOUT using defining the action name specifically (like HttpGet("New"))?

Comment: `[Route("[area]/invoice-categories/[action]"]`?

Comment: That works BUT now I have to specify /admin/invoice-categories/index to get the Index....how to I make /admin/invoice-categories/ automatically get the Index action (default)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a concept of default action in MVC Core attribute routing. Your alternatives are:

1. Create the route in the middleware where it is possible to specify a default action:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "invoice-categories",
       template: "{area}/invoice-categories/{action=Index}/{id?}",
       defaults: new { area = "admin", controller = "InvoiceCategories" });
   ```
2. Add an extra route on your `Index` action:

   ```
   [Area("admin")]
   [Route("[area]/invoice-categories/[action]"]
   class InvoiceCategoriesController {
       public IActionResult New() {}
       public IActionResult Edit(int id) {}

       [Route("[area]/invoice-categories"]
       public IActionResult Index() {}
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute routing is an all or nothing affair, at least in the context of a single controller (you can use attribute routing on some controllers and not others). The point is that once you specify a route on your controller, all actions either need a route specified as well, or they will default to `""`, or the exact route of the controller itself.

In other words, your `Index` action is fine as-is, but to remove the disambiguation, you'd need to specific `Route`, `HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc. on your other actions.